# Pressing home deletes content of dialpad

Tags: android

I have an application which opens a dialpad. When i press the home button to minimise the application and restore the application again the contents of UI which i had enetered in a dialpad are not there. What might the problem?

Comment: i guess this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Android does not save the states of all the UI elements on the layout when the application is paused, so you need to save all the needed info by yourself if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how the dialpad itself has been coded.
 Some dialpads actually saves the number when the application goes to "sleep". As I have tested quite a few devices I can not say specific dialers but I do know there are some that saves the state.

Comment: So u mean to say if at the app level we have to do the saving and retrieving of the data?

Comment: Well, the developer of the dialpad apps need to do that.